# Trying to set timezone for an event

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Like the title says, I'm creating an event, and it doesn't seem to set the correct timezone... what am I doing wrong?  For reference, I'm using 12:00PM as the start time.  The start time appears correctly, but not the timezone.  I do not want to convert the time to the user/device's timezone.

```
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();         
        cal.setTime(tDate);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra(Events.ALL_DAY, false);
        intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Title goes here");
        intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Los Angeles");
        intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
        intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Test");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I tried anything from `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` without any luck.

Comment: the tDate variable what times it contain, the best way to convert time is first convert it to UTC time zone and after that convert it to your time zone so convert tDate in to UTC and after that ti ur time zone hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

The intent method of adding an event (as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert)) doesn't appear to support the timezone extra—at least, not in the example given. Here are some pointers based on that example:

- You should use the `Intent.ACTION_INSERT` action
- You should set the URI via `setData()`, using the constant [CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html#CONTENT_URI)
- You should use the constant [CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME) instead of `"beginTime"`
- You should use the constant [CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY) instead of `Events.ALL_DAY`

If you need the timezone set you could use a ContentResolver to add the event without using the intent method.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but it works now (tested using `compileSdkVersion 31`).

```
Intent createEventIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Cayman")
    ...;
```

- To see the list of available timezones: `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.
- To use the current timezone: `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`.

[1] [Use an intent to insert an event](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#intent-insert)